# custom date field always return invalid

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I have a custom date field which I'm trying to update via Ruby API and I always get the same response:

```
[{"description"=>"PREMIUM STARTS AT: is invalid", "error"=>"InvalidValue", "ticket_field_id"=>xxxxxxxxx, "ticket_field_type"=>"FieldDate"}]}
```

I'm sending the date as follows: `"2017-01-17T13:54:51Z"`

I've tried also as UTC, got the same response. Which is the correct way to send this date?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, date format should be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. it will work for sure

Like

"custom_fields": [{"id": 46990467,"value":"2017-04-01"}]}}'

Answer (score 0):

This is the API call I made that worked

```
/api/v2/tickets/12058.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '{"ticket": {"status": "open", 
"custom_fields": [{"id": 46990467,"value":"2017-04-01"}]}}' -X PUT
```